# Mocking an injected object in a method return and UnsupportedOperationException method

Tags: junit, mockito

I have a class that returns an injected object using Mockito.  Everytime I test it, it returns a bull. How would I properly test it to return the correct object?

My class to test:

```
@Component
 public class CarImpl {
    @Inject
     private Engine v6EngineImpl;

    public Engine getEngine() {
        return v6EngineImpl;
}

public Exhaust getExhaust() {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported");
     }
}
```

Tests:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class CarTest {
    @InjectMocks
     private CarImpl carImpl;

@Mock
private Engine v6EngineImpl;

     @Test
     public void testGetEngine(){
       Engine v6EngineImpl = mock(V6EngineImpl.class);
       Engine engine = carImpl.getEngine();

      // always returns a bull no matter what, how to mock inject. 
      //return object correctly? 
      Assert.assertNotNull(engine);
   }

    @Test
     public void testGetExhaust() {
         // how to test thrown exception? 
     }
}
```

Thanks, I am not too familiar thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for not following explicit dependency principle? Just curious as that would  make testing the code in isolation easier.

Comment: Was just trying to use the Factory pattern which lead me down this path. Are you saying to just pass them in in the constructor instead of implicitly injecting them?

Comment: I can not reproduce your error. `carImpl.getEngine();` returns the injected mock.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class CarTest {

 @InjectMocks
 private CarImpl carImpl;

 @Mock
 private Engine v6EngineImpl;

     @Test
     public void testGetEngine(){
      Engine engine = carImpl.getEngine();

      //engine is the mock injected to CarImpl
      Assert.assertNotNull(engine);
      Assert.assertSame(engine,v6EngineImpl);
   }

    @Test(expected=UnsupportedOperationException.class)
     public void testGetExhaust() {
          carImpl.getExhaust();
     }
}
```